# C++ setGender method reverts to default values

Tags: c++

I've written the code bits below. I have a constructor which takes five arguments. Unfortunately, the setGender method spits out a default 'M' for all instances of a class rather than setting the gender to the specified parameter. What am I doing incorrectly? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
DateProfile::DateProfile(char gdr, 
   char searchGdr, int romanceScale, int financeScale, string theName)

bool DateProfile::setGender(char gdr)
{
   if (gdr != 'M' || gdr != 'F')
      return false;
   gender = gdr;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be writing code like that you should really learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (gdr != 'M' || gdr != 'F')` is **always** true, irrespective of input. If you're passing `'M'`, the second part of the expression is true. If you're passing anything else, the first part of the expression becomes true.

What you meant to write is `if (gdr != 'M' && gdr != 'F')` instead.

Increasing the warning level of your compiler may have helped you spot the error. Most compilers will warn about expressions always evaluating to a single value, or at least about the unreachable code following it.

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple mistake, but I've been staring at my code for hours. I appreciate your help!